# Angular material and responsive layout grid css framework

Tags: responsive-design, angular-material, material-design

I am working on an angular material application and we need to add responsive layout grid features to our application such as described here: [material design guidelines](https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#columns-gutters-and-margins).

However, I noticed that the angular material framework (https://material.angular.io) does not come with responsive layout grid features out of the box and angular flex layout (https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) is still in beta.

Can someone please suggest either a css framework that would fit in with angular material or any other solution in order to implement responsive layout grid?